# How to remove last filter from appender?

Tags: log4net, log4net-appender

How can I remove last filter from an appender in runtime? I can clear the filters, I can add a filter, but both methods alter private property `m_tailFilter` so when I set the Next property to null for the one before last filter, adding new filters afterwards does not work.

```
appender.AddFilter(filter); // works fine

appender.ClearFilters(); // works fine and adding filter again also works

var lastFilter = appender.FilterHead; // save previously last filter
appender.AddFilter(filter); // works fine
filter.Next = null; // works fine, i.e. removes the last filter
appender.AddFilter(filter); // doesn't work, i.e. this filter is ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

I will post here what I came with. I don't like it, it feels hacky and I think that there should be a better approach, but it seems to work for my scenario.

```
filter.Next = null;
var f = appender.FilterHead;
appender.ClearFilters();
appender.AddFilter(f);
```

So after removing the last filter from the chain, clear all filters and add the head again, this sets the tail correctly.